# 20 m LED WS2811 Pixel Stripe 12 V

Tags: arduino-uno, led, neopixel

i need some help for my masterthesis.
I plan an Light and Sound installation and for this I decided to use the shape of an Dodecahedron and I want to put LED RGB Pixel Stripes on the surfaces to light the space. Imagine it like a huge ceiling light in shape of a half Dodecahedron.

What I have:

- 1 x Arduino Starter Kit
- 4 x RGB LED Pixel Stripe: BTF-LIGHTING WS2811, 5M, 60 LEDs/m, 300LEDs RGB, DC12V

  - (0,3W/LED = 90W/5 M (1 LED Stripe) = 360 W/20 M an in total 40A (4 LED Stripes))
- 2 x LED Stripe: Minger SMD 2835, 5m, 300 LEDs, Dimmable, 6000K Kaltweiß, DC12V 
  (?)

The half of the Dodecahedron has 6 surfaces. Each surface gets like 300 to 350 cm RGB LEDs and 150 cm of Cold White.

My plan is to program the RGB LEDs with Strobe-Light (10 Hz) and changing colours and at the End of the installation the Cold White ("Daylight") is lighten up the space. (But this is another challenge for me ;))

How to connect all of them with my Arduino Uno? Any ideas?
Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, addressable RGB LED strips.  You can drive each string from an Arduino output, or daisy chain the signal thru all of them and just pump out the needed data using Adafruit Neopixel library, or the FastLED library. Make multiple power connections to keep the amount of 12V current going thru any one strip to a reasonable level.

Comment: Connect one output pin to each strip you are using.  In this video I have 4 strips connected to 4 output pins.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGOxbehyoM4

Comment: Actually, it sounds really easy. :) But I´m still afraid to connect all of it.

Comment: Here's the datasheet for the WS2811  https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Your big challenge is going to be power. Sum up the current requirements of ALL of your LED strips. Find a power supply that puts out ≈20% more than that. Read up on the max power you can pass through each strip, You can daisy-chain the power on multiple strips up to the current handling ability of the strips. Say the docs say a strip can pass max 5A through it, and each draws 1A. So you could chain the power connections of 5 of them one to the next, but no more than that. Also make sure you use power wire that's rated for your current needs. Remember your ground wires need to be heavy enough for your current needs as well. (The signal wires can be much lighter gauge.)

The signal lines don't need to follow the same topology as the power connections, but it's simpler to wire up if they do. (You could make the control lines of ALL of the LED strips in one long "snake" but run the power wires in a star pattern so the power wires don't exceed the current carrying limits of the strips or of your power wires. You could also wire both the power and the signal lines in a star pattern, and drive each point of the star with a separate Arduino pin.) You should be able to find a [**chart online that gives you the current carrying ability of different gauges of wire**](http://info.waytekwire.com/blog/automotive-wire-gauge-guide/). There, too, use wire that's rated a little over the current need, just to be safe. (That chart also talks about maximum length of wire to keep the voltage drop below 2%, which is a good idea.)